# React - Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <img>

Tags: reactjs

Trying to use **picture** element for responsive images inside my React app.
But I get this error:

> Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for **img**

```
                <section class='dd-image' data-ast-component='text' data-ast-separator='true' data-ast-title='some text' data-ast-desc='some text'>
                    <div class='image-wrapper'>
                        <picture class='cq-dd-image' data-ast-image-width='7676' data-ast-image-height='2399' data-ast-asset-path='test.jpg'>
                            <source media='unknown' srcset='./images/wallpaper-3840.jpg?imwidth=3840 3840w' data-srcset='./images/wallpaper-3840.jpg?imwidth=3840 3840w' data-rendition-width='3840' type='image/jpeg' >
                            <source media='unknown' srcset='./images/wallpaper-2880.jpg?imwidth=2880 2880w' data-srcset='./images/wallpaper-2880.jpg?imwidth=2880 2880w' data-rendition-width='2880' type='images/jpeg' >
                            <source media='unknown' srcset='./images/wallpaper-1920.jpg?imwidth=1920 1920w' data-srcset='./images/wallpaper-1920.jpg?imwidth=1920 1920w' data-rendition-width='1920' type='images/jpeg' >
                            <source media='(min-width: 1280px)' srcset='./images/wallpaper-1280.jpg?imwidth=1280 1280w' data-srcset='./images/wallpaper-1280.jpg?imwidth=1280 1280w' data-rendition-width='1280' type='images/jpeg' >
                            <source media='(min-width: 960px)' srcset='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=960 960w' data-srcset='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=960 960w' data-rendition-width='960' type='images/jpeg' >
                            <source media='(min-width: 640px)' srcset='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=640 640w' data-srcset='./images/wallpaper-640.jpg?imwidth=640 640w' data-rendition-width='640' type='images/jpeg' >
                            <source media='(min-width: 480px)' srcset='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=480 480w' data-srcset='./images/wallpaper-480.jpg?imwidth=480 480w' data-rendition-width='480' type='images/jpeg' >
                            <source media='(min-width: 384px)' srcset='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=384 384w' data-srcset='./images/wallpaper-384.jpg?imwidth=384 384w' data-rendition-width='384' type='images/jpeg' >
                            <source media='(min-width: 320px)' srcset='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=320 320w' data-srcset='./images/wallpaper-320.jpg?imwidth=320 320w' data-rendition-width='320' type='images/jpeg' >
                            <source media='(min-width: 240px)' srcset='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=240 240w' data-srcset='./images/wallpaper-240.jpg?imwidth=240 240w' data-rendition-width='240' type='images/jpeg' >
                            <source media='(min-width: 1px)' srcset='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=160 160w' data-srcset='./images/wallpaper-160.jpg?imwidth=160 160w' data-rendition-width='160' type='images/jpeg' > 
                            <img class='default-images loaded' src='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=960' alt='sample-image' data-src='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=960' loading='lazy' data-was-processed='true' > 
                        </picture>
                        <noscript>
                            <picture class='cq-dd-image' data-ast-component='image' data-ast-image-width='7676' data-ast-image-height='2399' data-ast-asset-path='test.jpg'> 
                              <img class='default-image' alt='sample-image' src='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=960' loading='lazy' > 
                            </picture>
                        </noscript>
                    </div>
                    <div class='text-over-image__body-wrapper' style='--background-gradient: radial-gradient(ellipse 50% 50% at 50% 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 82%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); background: radial-gradient(ellipse 50% 50% at 50% 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 82%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)'>
                        <div class='component__body text-over-image__body'>
                            <h2 class='text-over-image__headline'>Some sample text</h2>
                            <p class='text-over-image__text'>Some other text</p>
                            <div class='colour--palette-0 text-over-image__button-wrapper'>
                                <a href='#' class='text-over-image__button atomic--button-link' data-tracking='internal' data-tracking-link-location='text-over-image-promo' data-tracking-link-value='Read more'> <span class='atomic--button-link-wrapper'> <span class='atomic--button-link-label text-label'>Read more</span> </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

How can I fix that parsing error?

Comment: The answer is in the error. At the end of the <img> elements (and any element for that matter) should be closing tags. So it should look like <img class='default-images loaded' ....> **</img>**

Answer (score 1):

All elements should have closing tags. You have multiple  elements with no closing. They should look like

```
<img (your attributes here)> </img>
```

OR be self-closing with a forward slash, like this

```
<img (your attributes here) />
```

So, using your `<img>` element at the end of your `<picture>` element as an example, use one of the methods I described above

```
<img class='default-images loaded' src='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=960' alt='sample-image' data-src='./images/wallpaper-960.jpg?imwidth=960' loading='lazy' data-was-processed='true' />
```

Answer (score 1):

React is expecting a closing tag for `img` element.
There are two ways to do that here:

1. `<img ...your code... />` (notice the `/`)
2. `<img ...your code...></img>`